# I need the text color of the right section of my nav-bar turn white, using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I need the text color of my nav-bar (white), while the background stays `primary-subtle`, using Bootstrap! When combine, how can I override the build in functions of Bootstrap using CSS.

Details of code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary-subtle" data-bs-theme="dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href=""> CONNECT </a>
<ul class="nav  ms-auto" >
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active:text-decoration:none"  href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active:text-decoration:none"  href="">Signup</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active:text-decoration:none"  href="">Reviews</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active:text-decoration:none"  href="">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

I expect a back-ground color of `primary-subtle` (I have) and a white text color for my navbar -> Home, Sign up, Reviews and Login (There is no white text color)

Comment: Please post the html and css post in text instead of the picture :)

Comment: Yes, I'll do that now. Still learning thanks for the insight. @VictorPieper

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can override bootstrap css by adding `!important` to your own css:

```
a {
  color: white !important;
}

.nav-link {
    color: white !important;
}

.white-text {
    color: white !important;
 }

<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active:text-decoration:none white-text"  href="">Home</a></li>
```

You can put it on an element, change the nav-link class or even create a new class if you don't want it on all the a elements.

Or you can use link light class from bootstrap

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active:text-decoration:none link-light"  href="">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Here, We do not need to write custom css. We can use `link-light` css class for that.

Comment: @VictorPieper Thanks, I was able to figure it out. Appreciate the help.